Only allow one "not specific" IP address to connect to a port at a time with unlimited parallel connections?
I have a proxy server listening on port 60000 that redirects all traffic sent to it to a VPN.
What I want to achieve is: At any given moment, only allow a single person/IP address(not a specific one) to make as many (parallel)connections as they want to this proxy server.
Or to put it in other words:
When someone connects, check and see if they are the first one. If so, dedicate the port entirely to them and allow them to make as many parallel connections as they need. Others will have to wait for this person to close the connection before they could try connecting.

The first thing I tried was to limit the amount of connections with the limit module of iptables, in order to not allow more than 1 simultaneous connection to the port like this:
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 60000 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 1 -j REJECT

But that causes a problem; This is Firefox loading Google and Askubuntu, routed through a local proxy so I could track it:
sudo ss -tan dport = :2080
State                    Recv-Q                Send-Q                               Local Address:Port                                 Peer Address:Port                Process                
TIME-WAIT                0                     0                                        127.0.0.1:58652                                   127.0.0.1:2080                                       
ESTAB                    0                     0                                        127.0.0.1:51874                                   127.0.0.1:2080                                       
ESTAB                    0                     0                                        127.0.0.1:58646                                   127.0.0.1:2080                                       
TIME-WAIT                0                     0                                        127.0.0.1:53360                                   127.0.0.1:2080                                       
TIME-WAIT                0                     0                                        127.0.0.1:53286                                   127.0.0.1:2080                                       
TIME-WAIT                0                     0                                        127.0.0.1:53268                                   127.0.0.1:2080                                       
TIME-WAIT                0                     0                                        127.0.0.1:53330                                   127.0.0.1:2080                                       
TIME-WAIT                0                     0                                        127.0.0.1:53314                                   127.0.0.1:2080                                       
ESTAB                    0                     0                                        127.0.0.1:40942                                   127.0.0.1:2080                                       
TIME-WAIT                0                     0                                        127.0.0.1:53334                                   127.0.0.1:2080                                       
ESTAB                    0                     0                                        127.0.0.1:35864                                   127.0.0.1:2080

And as you can see, it need way more than a single connection. On top of that, websites like YouTube alone make the list of connections so big it doesn't even fit within my terminal height.
So limiting the amount of connections to 1 doesn't even allow Firefox to load a static website(tested this).

The second thing I tried doing was implementing this logic:

Allow established & related connections.
Is the new connection towards port 60000? Send them to MYCHAIN.

In MYCHAIN

Seen the source IP in the last 10 seconds? Allow it.
Source IP not seen in the last 10 seconds in the list? Reject them.
Add the IP to the list.

So here are the commands:
sudo iptables -N MYCHAIN
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 60000 -m state --state NEW -j MYCHAIN
sudo iptables -A MYCHAIN -m recent --name TEST_LIST --update --seconds 10 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A MYCHAIN -m recent --name TEST_LIST '!' --rcheck --seconds 10 -j REJECT 
sudo iptables -A MYCHAIN -m recent --name TEST_LIST --set -j ACCEPT

But this also causes a problem. Lets now try to access a website form this proxy using Firefox:
First packet comes in for a new connection to port 60000

Ignores the first rule; It's a new connection
The second rule sends it to MYCHAIN; It's a new connection and headed for port 60000

In MYCHAIN:

Ignores the first rule; IP hasn't been seen before so the recent module returns false
Gets rejected; The IP hasn't been seen before and with the exclamation mark, the recent module returns true.

So the initial connection can never even be made for the IP to be stored, so that it can later look it up and decide whether it's a new person trying to connect or another parallel one from the same user.

The last thing I tried was to swap the last rule in MYCHAIN (sudo iptables -A MYCHAIN -m recent --name TEST_LIST --set -j ACCEPT) with either the first or second one like the following:
sudo iptables -A MYCHAIN -m recent --name TEST_LIST --set -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A MYCHAIN -m recent --name TEST_LIST --update --seconds 10 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A MYCHAIN -m recent --name TEST_LIST '!' --rcheck --seconds 10 -j REJECT 

or
sudo iptables -A MYCHAIN -m recent --name TEST_LIST --update --seconds 10 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A MYCHAIN -m recent --name TEST_LIST --set -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A MYCHAIN -m recent --name TEST_LIST '!' --rcheck --seconds 10 -j REJECT 

Well this approach will solve the problem of not even being able to connect by putting the source IP in the TEST_LIST list, which allows the ACCEPT rule to return true and accept the connection, but it will not solve the main problem of not letting others in while someone is already using the service:
If another person tries to connect at the same time, their IP address will also be put it the list; Resulting in the ACCEPT rule to return true, thus continuing to let traffic through and also make the REJECT rule always return false, therefore it never blocks the connection of the other person.

If there's something I might have forgotten to write here, another tool I should be using for this purpose, a different method with which I should be approaching this problem or some obvious/tiny detail I missed, I'd appreciate it if you could help me figure it out.
Tank you for taking your time to read this.

Edits: Ubuntu Version 22.04 LTS

There is no mention of Ubuntu or any flavor of Ubuntu in this question. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, added it. @DavidDE

Just a quick idea, you could probably use fail2ban with custom-written rules and actions to ban all other IP addresses from connecting to that port once the first client connects. However, you need something that will log a message about that first connection to some logfile that fail2ban will monitor.
